# File corrupted on external SSD using Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd, file-corruption

It has been a while but sometimes I find corrupted files that are initially correctly saved on an external SSD.  When I try to reopen them (it generally happens the day after), they are corrupt.

I'm using Windows 10 and several applications to edit these files (mostly Excel, Powerpoint, Notepad++).

All of the files are stored on an external SSD that I use among different windows 10 pcs I own.

Examples of the corrupted files I find might be ASCII files (php or txt). These files appear to now have non ASCII values instead of the original plain text.

Other times there might be Word, Powerpoint, or Excel files that MS Office neither can open nor repair.

I thought it was a SSD specific problem, but I changed to a different SSD and had the same problem.

Even when changing PCs I wasn't able to get rid off this annoying problem. It's like the Windows 10 file systems doesn't properly allocate sectors on the SSD disks, mixing contents of different files.

I wonder if any of you had the same problem and found the cause.

Comment: Are you disconnecting the SSD properly?  Eject removable device icon.

Comment: Are you running chkdsk on the volume to determine if you have actually messed up the file system or only individual files?  I am guessing that your file system has errors because of what @John is asking in the other comment.

Comment: I generally shutdown the system without disconnecting the SSD (I physically extraxt the SDD after the PC is turned off). In the most messy SDD i run chkdsk but it stops at 49%. So I've transferred all the files to a new one, but this morning i found the same problem in 4 files I edited on the new one. I've never experienced this kind of problems with external HDD.

Comment: The files might have been corrupted before/during the transfer.

Comment: is this a very inexpensive yet large capacity SSD,? see for example https://twitter.com/RayRedacted/status/1562914396732801025?cxt=HHwWgoDS-Z6Xy7ArAAAA

Comment: These faked firmwares will display a proper directory listing (usually) but the data is just "looped" and thrashes old data by overwriting. Sounds like "mixing contents of different files"

Comment: I don't think I'm using cheap SDD, the ones I'm referring to are SanDisk 500GB Extreme SSD. Following the comment from John I've started to disconnect the SDDs before to turn off the PC. See if it works.

Comment: Did you also change cables you use to connect the drive?

Answer (score 0):

This really seems to be a fake drive.

So the firmware is being modified to show a larger capacity. As flash drives save the date non-linear, everything will look fine at the beginning. Finally, old data is being overwritten by new data, and the result is corrupted files.

You can check your drives with [H2testw](https://www.heise.de/download/product/h2testw-50539), which is advertised for Windows XP, but will run fine on Windows 10 with no installation.

Comment: He changed PC and SSD. That makes this hypothesis less likely.